# Passing FFMPEG AvFrame data from c++ to JAVA

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I need to pass the FFMPEG 'raw' data back to my JAVA code in order to display it on the screen.
I have a native method that deals with FFMPEG and after that calls a method in java that takes Byte[] (so far) as an argument.

Byte Array that is passed is read by JAVA but when doing `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmap, 0, bitmap.length);` it returns null. I have printed out the array and I get 200k of elements (which are expected), but cannot be decoded. So far what I'm doing is taking data from `AvFrame->data` casting it to `unsigned char *` and then casting that to `jbyterArray`. After all the casting, I pass the `jbyteArray` as argument to my JAVA method. Is there something I'm missing here? Why won't `BitmapFactory` decode the array into an image for displaying?

## EDIT 1.0

Currently I am trying to obtain my image via

```
public void setImage(ByteBuffer bmp) {
        bmp.rewind();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1920, 1080, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(bmp);

        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            ImageView imgViewer = findViewById(R.id.mSurfaceView);
            imgViewer.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        });
    }
```

But I keep getting an exception

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewDirectByteBuffer called with pending exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels
at void android.graphics.Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(java.nio.Buffer) (Bitmap.java:657)
at void com.example.asmcpp.MainActivity.setSurfaceImage(java.nio.ByteBuffer)
```

## Edit 1.1

So, here is the full code that is executing every time there is a frame incoming. Note that the ByteBuffer is created and passed from within this method

```
void VideoClientInterface::onEncodedFrame(video::encoded_frame_t &encodedFrame) {
    AVFrame *filt_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    auto frame = std::shared_ptr<video::encoded_frame_t>(new video::encoded_frame_t,
                                                         [](video::encoded_frame_t *p) { if (p) delete p; });
    if (frame) {
        frame->size = encodedFrame.size;
        frame->ssrc = encodedFrame.ssrc;
        frame->width = encodedFrame.width;
        frame->height = encodedFrame.height;
        frame->dataType = encodedFrame.dataType;
        frame->timestamp = encodedFrame.timestamp;
        frame->frameIndex = encodedFrame.frameIndex;
        frame->isKeyFrame = encodedFrame.isKeyFrame;
        frame->isDroppable = encodedFrame.isDroppable;

        frame->data = new char[frame->size];
        if (frame->data) {
            memcpy(frame->data, encodedFrame.data, frame->size);
            AVPacket packet;
            av_init_packet(&packet);

            packet.dts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;
            packet.pts = encodedFrame.timestamp;

            packet.data = (uint8_t *) encodedFrame.data;
            packet.size = encodedFrame.size;

            int ret = avcodec_send_packet(m_avCodecContext, &packet);
            if (ret == 0) {
                ret = avcodec_receive_frame(m_avCodecContext, m_avFrame);
                if (ret == 0) {
                    m_transform = sws_getCachedContext(
                            m_transform, // previous context ptr
                            m_avFrame->width, m_avFrame->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, // src
                            m_avFrame->width, m_avFrame->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, // dst
                            SWS_BILINEAR, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr // options
                    );

                    auto decodedFrame = std::make_shared<video::decoded_frame_t>();
                    decodedFrame->width = m_avFrame->width;
                    decodedFrame->height = m_avFrame->height;
                    decodedFrame->size = m_avFrame->width * m_avFrame->height * 3;
                    decodedFrame->timeStamp = m_avFrame->pts;

                    decodedFrame->data = new unsigned char[decodedFrame->size];

                    if (decodedFrame->data) {
                        uint8_t *dstSlice[] = {decodedFrame->data,
                                               0,
                                               0};// outFrame.bits(), outFrame.bits(), outFrame.bits()

                        const int dstStride[] = {decodedFrame->width * 3, 0, 0};
                        sws_scale(m_transform, m_avFrame->data, m_avFrame->linesize,
                                                  0, m_avFrame->height, dstSlice, dstStride);

                        auto m_rawData = decodedFrame->data;
                        auto len = strlen(reinterpret_cast<char *>(m_rawData));
                        if (frameCounter == 10) {
                            jobject newArray = GetJniEnv()->NewDirectByteBuffer(m_rawData, len);
                            GetJniEnv()->CallVoidMethod(m_obj, setSurfaceImage, newArray);
                            frameCounter = 0;

                        }
                        frameCounter++;

                    }
                } else {
                    av_packet_unref(&packet);
                }
            } else {
                av_packet_unref(&packet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not entirely sure I am even doing that part correctly. If you see any errors in this, feel free to point them out.

Comment: I wrote an answer in the assumption you meant a primitive array (`byte[]`) instead of an array of objects (`Byte[]`).

Comment: @Botje that is exactly what I need. I am trying to incorporate your answer into my code. Just dealing with ByteBuffer ```UnsupportedOperationException```  exceptions right now.

Comment: @Botje edited the question with some more details, based on your comment on your answer.

Comment: How big is your `ByteBuffer`? It should be 4*1920*1080 bytes.

Comment: @Botje No damn idea. I've added the C++ code that calls that JAVA Method from first edit. The entire Function.

Comment: Using `strlen` on arbitrary binary data does not make much sense. From your code it is clear you receive an RGB(24) bitmap, while android wants a ARGB image. You will need to ask FFmpeg to produce ARGB (or RGB8888), then tell Java you have a buffer of size `m_avFrame->width * m_avFrame->height * 4` (which should go in `decodedFrame->size`). Finally, make sure that `decodedFrame->data` remains *live* for the entire duration that Java is using it, otherwise your program will still crash. You could store `decodedFrame` somewhere in your object, for example.

Comment: @Botje Okay, so we had to do some code clean-up and a little structure fix to implement RGBA (Alpha being the last one for some reason). Problem is now solved and the stream is working just fine. Also dealt with some memory leaks in the code that were causing OOM exception to be thrown. Thank you so much for point out the Format.  (Ain't using sizeof() anymore, that was a vague attempt at something that just stayed there...)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast native byte arrays to `jbyteArray` and expect it to work. A `byte[]` is an actual object with `length` field, a reference count, and so on.

Use [`NewDirectByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#new_direct_byte_buffer) instead to wrap your byte buffer into a Java [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), from where you can grab the actual `byte[]` using `.array()`.

Note that this JNI operation is relatively expensive, so if you expect to do this on a per-frame basis, you might want to pre-allocate some bytebuffers and tell FFmpeg to write directly into those buffers.

Comment: So, I'm obtaining the ```ByteBuffer``` object, but calling ```.array()``` on it throws ```UnsupportedOperationException``` at me, and crashes everything.

Comment: Doh. It may be that `.array()` only works for `ByteBuffer`s that wrap a `byte[]`. Plan B: Use [`Bitmap#copyPixelsFromBuffer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsFromBuffer(java.nio.Buffer)) (found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39751247/1548468))